# Intercept soft keyboard Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

As in the title, my code is:

```
final int MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX = 150;                              // Threshold for minimal keyboard height
    final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();     // Top-level window decor view

    // Register global layout listener.
    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        private final Rect windowVisibleDisplayFrame = new Rect();
        private int lastVisibleDecorViewHeight;

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowVisibleDisplayFrame);   // Retrieve visible rectangle inside window
            final int visibleDecorViewHeight = windowVisibleDisplayFrame.height();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)swipeRefreshLayout.getLayoutParams();
            int marginBottom = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_footer);

            if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight != 0) {
                if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight > visibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX) {     // Keyboard show
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                else if (lastVisibleDecorViewHeight + MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PX < visibleDecorViewHeight) { // Keyboard hide
                    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, marginBottom);
                }
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            lastVisibleDecorViewHeight = visibleDecorViewHeight;    // Save current decor view height for the next call
        }
    });
```

this works fine, but if the keyboard changes in size, for example from alphanumeric to numeric, setMargins is not completely 0 but passes the first case with setMargins(0, 0, 0, marginBottom).

Comment: how about if first of all, you state clearly what are you trying to accomplish, and why? I personally doubt you would have any real need to manipulate the keyboard's dimension at runtime.

Comment: I have a navigation view called "footer" at the bottom of the web view layout and if the keyboard shows it I want this footer not visible

Comment: if the footer is in your activity's layout, the system keyboard will always be on top of it, so I still don't see what is your problem ... trying to understand and help you out here :)

Comment: also snapshots of your problem usually help people to understand :)

Comment: In the activity there are the web view at the top and the footer at the bottom, the height of the footer is "x", the height of the web view is match parent and has marginBottom equal to "x", so the footer does not go over to webview..

Comment: but you will have your activity (say main_activity) which layout will have the webview and the footer, possibly both children's of an outer layout (say a relative_layout). At this point you define the keyboard against your main_activity, so it will appear on top of all the outer layout, included both the webview and the footer. Right?

Comment: I want when the web view high is "x" then the footer is visible, if it is smaller the footer is not visible.

Comment: From how you describe it, this is what I understand you want: you've webview and footer, and when keyboard shows up, you want to show it so that all the webview is still visible.
Android's layouts are responsive, so you shouldn't think by pixels or dimenstions; you should instead simply set the visibility of the footer to 'gone' when the keyboard is shown, and also set in the Manifest the windowSoftInputMode property of your activity to 'adjustResize' to let it shrink above the shown keyboard (after you set 'gone' for the footer, it will expand to take all the screen).

Comment: also remember: you've no guarantee that on all phones, on all OSes and on all vendors the keyboard shown will be the type you ask for: sometimes it will be a different type, sometimes it will be the same type, but with extra space for dictionary, and so on.